# Can Apache ZooKeeper 4lw (FourLetterWord) be used with mTLS (mutual Transport Layer Security)?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, mtls

I've used 4lw over unsecured connections, but I want to use 4lw over connections secured with mTLS. So far no success.

If this isn't supported, what is recommended in place of 4lw? AdminServer?

Answer (score 0):

Using Zookeeper with mTLS and ncat 4lw

1. Create keystore in p12 format from JKS (nc need PEM)

   keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore **keystore.jks** -destkeystore **keystore.p12** -srcstoretype jks -deststoretype pkcs12
2. Export private key and cert to PEM

   openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.p12 -nokeys -out ~/cert.pem
   openssl pkcs12 -in keystore.p12 -out ~/key.pem
3. Run nc with --ssl options (need password for private key)

   echo "stat" | nc --ssl --ssl-cert ~/cert.pem --ssl-key ~/key.pem zookeeper_host port

make your file with private key secured (correct file permission, not read for group and all) and encrypted!